# SESSION['username'] is not set

Tags: php, session, redirect, header

I have a form which takes the username and puts it in a SESSION after submit.
Now when I check if SESSION username exists and echo it, it shows me the result perfectly, but when I want to redirect to another page if the same SESSION is not empty it tells me that the SESSION doesn't exist.

I don't get it?!

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user = $_POST['username']; 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;

    echo $_SESSION['username']; // This shows me the result perfectly

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('location:index.php?page=dashboard&user='.$_SESSION['username'].'');
    }
    else{
    echo "SESSION user isn't set."; // This is the result I get from the isset()
    }
}
```

Value 10106 is the value I want to get in this part, my page prints this:

```
SESSION user isn't set10106
```

It does the redirect but can't load anything because SESSION is empty, but when I click on my button logout it does show me the value in the URL:

```
action=logout&user=10106
```

So that means the session is set. But the isset() still gives me a false result.
I didn't forget the session_start(), else my echo wouldn't give me result either.

This the form I submit:

```
<form action='index.php?page=login' method='post'>
    <table id='login'>
       <tr>
          <td colspan=2><br></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>User:</td>
          <td><input type='username' name='username'></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type='password' name='password'></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan=2><input type='submit' name='submit'></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

EXTRA INFO:

When I click submit, it stays on the same page, the URL didnt changed but my menu did. The menu changes when SESSION username is set, so when I click on another URL in the menu it shows me the SESSION in the URL.

```
index.php?page=new_call&user=10106
```

EDIT: **OK, so the problem isn't the SESSION which isn't set, it's the redirect that doesn't work. After submitting the form it should redirect but stays on the same page right now.**

Comment: did you initialize session?

Comment: you need to start each script you want to use sessions in with session_start();

Comment: If I didn't then my echo wouldn't give me my result ;)

Comment: You must have session_start() at the start of each script.

Comment: Session_start() is at the top of my script, this is just a little part of code.

Comment: @dakshbhatt21 You should've read the question first, he says the value echoes but `isset` returns `false`

Comment: Session_start() is in my script.

Comment: Does your browser have cookies disabled?

Comment: Yes, I checked everything, that's why this is so strange.

Comment: This is seriously funny, there's no way this can't work..

Comment: 10106 is the result I want to get, and this is what my page prints: session user isn't set10106

Comment: It does a redirect but can't load anything because the value of session['username'] is missing, but when I click on my button logout it shows me the value in the URL: action=logout&user=10106 , so it DOES set it. But why does the isset give me a return false?

Comment: Are you using output buffering? Because normally (no `ob_` used) after `echo`ed, you won't be able to `header()` because "headers are already sent".

Comment: Do you have code for the form you're submitting to get the $_POST value?

Comment: is the header("location:") redirecting to the same page?

Comment: header location is redirecting to index.php?page=dashboard, everything is loaded via my index page

Comment: Here is a question for you.  Why are you passing $_SESSION['username'] as a get value at all if it is a $_SESSION array?  Couldn't you just as easily do : header('location index.php?page=dashboard') and then simply call the session value with $_SESSION['username'] ???

Comment: Something I don't understand: you said you got "SESSION user isn't set10106", but according to the order of your code, it should be "10106SESSION user isn't set"; You said "It does the redirect but can't load anything because SESSION is empty", but if your code goes into the `else` route, it shouldn't do the redirect. Are you posting the actual code?

Comment: This is the actual code and indeed, I also noticed this.

Comment: I tried your code and it redirects to index.php?page=dashboard&user=test (I used 'test' as an input). I didn't get an echo for the 'test' which is expected.

Comment: You didn't get the result of session user isn't set? I do get the echo but the result of session user isn't set.

Comment: I can only get that error if i comment out $_SESSION['username'] = $user;

Comment: Right now, the session works, I don't know how but it works, it's the redirect that doesnt do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: The HTML you posted has absolutely nothing that outputs "$_SESSION user isn't set10106".  That's what we should be seeing.  The result.  That way we can see what the page is trying to do AFTER the fact, not beforehand.  Perhaps you could just edit that part you added and replace it with that version of the HTML output.

Comment: The part that seems to have everyone confused is why 10106 is coming after "$_SESSION user isn't set" rather than before it.  That's the reason I want to see the HTML for that output so we can see why it is stacking up in that order because based on the php file it shouldn't.

Comment: Right now it just shows me 10106, but the redirect refuses to do his work.

Comment: Well, your redirect directs to the same page with a new get value, right?  How many php files do you have other than index.php?  What does your url say after the problem code executes in the browser?  I am guessing //index.php?page=something and if "something" is "dashboard" then technically it did its job.  The problem could be in how you're using the $_GET value in that file for that particular page.

Comment: It stays on index.php?page=login while it should redirect to index.php?page=dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to structure your code to something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page=$_GET['page'];
}
else{
    $page="";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //log in submit
    $user = $_POST['username']; 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;

    echo $_SESSION['username']; // This shows me the result perfectly

    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('location:index.php?page=dashboard&user='.$_SESSION['username'].'');
    }
    else{
    echo "SESSION user isn't set."; // This is the result I get from the isset()
    }
}
if($page=="dashboard"){ //dashboard page

?>
Dashboard page<br>
Your session: <?php echo($_SESSION['username']); ?>
<?php
}
else{ //login page
?>
<form action='' method='post'>
    <table id='login'>
       <tr>
          <td colspan=2><br></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>User:</td>
          <td><input type='username' name='username'></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type='password' name='password'></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan=2><input type='submit' name='submit'></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])){

So this will always pass since 'if session user is set or is not set.

Comment: my bad, i updated the condition to check for isset and !empty

Comment: Wait... does that work?  You can put plain HTML between a conditional with split php tags?  Learn something new every day. :D

Comment: Yes that works ;) , though I prefer to just echo the divs etc

Answer (score 2):

```
session_start();
$user = "admin";

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
    if($_POST){
        if($_POST['username'] == $user){
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user;
        } else {
            echo "SESSION user isn't set.<br>";
        }

    }
    echo "input your session username ";
} else {
    echo  "Youve got Session " . $_SESSION['user_name'];
}
```

try it :D

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {// I assume this tests to see if it was passed by a form
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; 
    //Sets $_SESSION to the post username in 1 step.

    echo $_SESSION['username']; // Prints the contents of $_SESSION['username']

    if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {//if the above echoes, then this must be true...
        header("Location: index.php?page=dashboard");
        }
    else
        {
        echo '$_SESSION["user"] isn't set.'; // This is the result I get from the isset()
        }
    }
```

If you're really set on making the $_SESSION['username'] value be in the URL then do this instead.

```
header("Location: index.php?page=dashboard&user=" . $_SESSION['username'] );
```

Comment: Yes well, the result is; $_SESSION user isn't set10106. 10106 is the value I want to achieve which the echo returns.

Comment: Perhaps after all of this confusion it wouldn't be bad form to just hit ctrl-u and copy and paste the HTML output that gives you "$_SESSION user isn't set10106." so we can see what is going on inside the html.

Comment: OK, I'll post the HTML too.